"doocument is not defined error" in vue tests
I am trying to make test units for my vue app. Most of the vue components use typescript, which was the first error I got.I am trying to use vitest for the tests. The tests have a format similar to this:
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '../../src/components/HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld);

  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message'
     expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg)
  })
})

I am getting this error:
FAIL  tests/unit/example.spec.ts [ tests/unit/example.spec.ts ]
ReferenceError: document is not defined
 ❯ Proxy.mount node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.cjs.js:8371:14
 ❯ tests/unit/example.spec.ts:5:19
      3| 
      4| describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
      5|   const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld);
       |                   ^
      6|
      7|   it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {

I really don't know what is the meanin of this error, and I haven't been able to find a solution.
These are the vitest.config.js and the package.json
vitest.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({ 
  plugins: [vue()], 
  test: { globals: true } 
})

package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test": "vitest",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.5",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2",
    "vitest": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7"
  },
}


share your vitest.config.ts and package.json

vitest.config.js:
'import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [vue()],
test:{
globals:true,
}
})'

package.json:
'"dependencies": {
"axios": "^1.6.7",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
"core-js": "^3.8.3",
"vue": "^3.2.13",
"vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
"vue-router": "4",
"xlsx": "^0.18.5"
},

you should edit your question to include such details.  its very difficult to read unformatted code in comments.  I've made an edit for you adding the information given, but it looks like you only provided a small snippet of your package.json, so you should edit to provide the full information.

one thing you should probably do is add a browser environment to your test config.  test: { environment: 'jsdom', globals: true }.  you may need to install jsdom if you don't already have it, npm i jsdom -D

I have jsdom, but there were errors adding it so I had to force it.

I don't know what you mean.  errors installing it, or errors adding it to vitest config?  how did you force it?  is it working?  is there still any problem?  please be as detailed as possible in what steps you're taking and results.
